# Connection String and Driver Setup When Connecting to a MySQL Farm Behind a HaProxy

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, haproxy

Is it possible to connect to a cluster of MySQL servers behind HaProxy using Spring and JPA? I tried several combinations of search phrases trying to find a lead but was not successful.

Should it be that the application is run on multiple instances, with each instance having a dedicated connection to a MySQL instance? And the MySQL instances using a multi-master setup so that the data is circularly replicated between each other allowing each instance to serve up the most up to date data?

I'm not really sure, I just need a lead in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

As per the recommendation below on changing the question, I want to know how to setup the connection string and driver when connecting to a mysql farm behind a haproxy.

Comment: If the MySQL/HaProxy thingy is set up correctly there is nothing that can stop you from using it with JPA

Comment: How do you create a datasource connection to it? What driver do you use? That's what I can't seem to find.

Comment: So perhaps it is a good idea to change your question and ask "how do I have to set up the connection string and driver when connecting to a mysql farm behind a haproxy" ? ;-)

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question and asked it as per your suggestion. Do you have a source of direction for me so that I can find the answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a datasource in spring connecting to a farm of MariaDB/MySQL servers behind HaProxy is no different than connecting to a single MariaDB/Mysql server.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://IPADDRESS-OR-HOST:3306/DATABASE?
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&maxAllowedPacket=512000
spring.datasource.username= USER
spring.datasource.password= PASSWORD
```

The only thing that I changed was the host IP/HOST and it just worked. I did have to create the database on one of the nodes which replicated to the rest so that Spring can create the tables and test data...